# Is it possible to know number of requests (method calls) made per second from an IP in meteor apps?

Tags: meteor, rate-limiting, meteor-accounts

I see there is a DDP rate limiter but which will have the calls count per second per session.
I have a use case where I need to see all calls from a specific IP address per second. Please suggest any packages that could help in this regard. Any suggestions on how to achieve this is appreciable, thanks.